# Django OperationalError 'no such column:' sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

For my basic, rudimentary Django CMS, in my effort to add a toggle feature to publish / unpublish a blog post (I’ve called my app ‘essays’ and the class object inside my models is `is_published`), I’ve encountered an OperationalError when trying to use the Admin Dashboard to add essay content.  I’m expecting to be able to switch a tick box to publish/unpublish but now I can’t even access the Dashboard.

Here is part of the  traceback from my Django server:

```
File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2020/<projectdir>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2020/<projectdir>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: essays_essayarticle.is_published
```

The debug traceback reinforces the OperationalError above:

```
OperationalError at /admin/essays/essayarticle/
no such column: essays_essayarticle.is_published

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://<DN>.ngrok.io/admin/essays/essayarticle/
Django Version:2.2.11
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such column: essays_essayarticle.is_published
Exception Location:
/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2020/<projectdir>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:
/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2020/<projectdir>/venv/bin/python
`Fri, 1 May 2020 19:37:31 +0000
```

Exception Value indicates ‘no such column’ which is a reference to my db. I’m running SQlite3 for test purposes. Prior to this OperationalError, I was troubleshooting issues with a DummyNode and "isinstance django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration". The previous solution I arrived at was to delete my migrations in two of my apps. This SO answer is the particular solution that resolved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195727/6095646

As per **@Laila Buabbas**'s suggestion, to clarify, I deleted my migrations directory and invoked: `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`  for each of my two apps.  So that previous SQLite issue has been resolved. But I can’t figure out this new OperationalError, described above.

Is the issue is with my views.py / models.py (copied below)? I can't narrow it down any more specific than that. Here is part of the  class defined in my app’s models.py (with the new potential problem line added at the end):

```
class EssayArticle(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   web_address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   web_address_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, max_length=512)
   content = models.TextField(blank=True)
   is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Here are the relevant lines from the applicable function in my views.py:

```
def article(request, web_address):
   try:
       article = EssayArticle.objects.get(
           web_address_slug=web_address)  # .filter(is_published=True)
   except EssayArticle.DoesNotExist:
       raise Http404('Article does not exist!')
   context = {
       'article': article,
   }
   return render(request, 'essays/article.html', context)
```

Commenting in our out the `.filter(is_published=True)` doesn't stop or change the debug error.

My local dev box is Manjaro Linux with Django v2.2.11. I’m running Python v3.8.2.

Here are some of the resources I have already leveraged:

- [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)
- [Django OperationalError: no such column: on pythonanywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863318/django-operationalerror-no-such-column-on-pythonanywhere)
- [Django 1.8 OperationalError: no such column:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842149/django-1-8-operationalerror-no-such-column)
- [Django tutorial01 OperationalError: no such column: polls_choice.question_text_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451706/django-tutorial01-operationalerror-no-such-column-polls-choice-question-text-i)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't column is_published in essays_essayarticle table of your db try to add column in db  by adding new migration and see the change for a table whether this column is going to be added.

The error isn't in your view rather it is in query.

Comment: When you say 'add a new migration' do you mean `$ python manage.py makemigrations`?   I ask because I thought I clarified that I already tried that - - I used makemigrations and migrating which didn't resolve my issue. Is there another way to add a new migration as you say?

Answer (score 1):

Its looking like your migration with the same name is already triggered, thats why Django is not able to create new column,

You have to look into the table `django_migrations` in database find and delete the migration record. You need to compare your migrations with `django_migrations` in database then only you will find the issue/error you are getting

Once you delete the migration from `django_migrations` in database,Run the migration

```
./manage.py migrate
```

then might your problem get solved

Comment: Yes, deleting and building a migration from scratch would fix the issue. Even though it is a test case, I still need to preserve the data being stored. I can't build a db from scratch. How do I add/delete the right table/row/column/entry? Here is what it looks like in the tool that I am using: https://imgur.com/NeIxvx8

Comment: This is the tool I'm using pictured in that image above: https://sqlitebrowser.org/
Is there another way to achieve the same effect but in a unix shell via CLI?

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-commands/ this might help you on playing with sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you deleted the migrations folder, if so when you makemigrations and migrate write the name of you app at the end

example

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted the migrations folder for my two web apps and invoked `makemigrations` for both specific apps. The OperationalError persists. I updated my question so as to avoid other people having to make the same assumption you had to make.